# unable to import OleDbConnection in dotnet core entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, oledbconnection

unable to import OleDbConnection in dotnetcore entity framework while transferring data from excel to sqlserver

Comment: What are you trying to do, how are you trying to do this and where is the error occurring? Is it a compile time error, or does it occur during run time? There's way too little information in this question to be able to help...

Answer (score 10):

OleDb is now available for .NET Core.
[System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb) is available on NuGet.org

Comment: Yes, it is available for .NET Core... But...
 
Visual studio (2022):
Warning CA1416 - This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'OleDbConnection.Open()' is only supported on: 'windows'.
--
Debian 11, dotnet 6.0: 
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.OleDb is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 8):

OleDb is not available in .NET Core, probably because it's not cross platform.

Have a look at the [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netcore-2.0) in .NET Core 2.0.

**Alternative**
For a decent alternative, have a look at the answer to this Stack Overflow question: [How to get OleDb for reading excel in asp.net core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438377/how-to-get-oledb-for-reading-excel-in-asp-net-core-project)