# How to access oledb on android in Xamarin

Tags: android, ms-access, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im having trouble with my connection to my microsoft access database with my Xamarin forms application.
This is the code that i have to check if my connection is successfull

[image]

And this is the error when that code executes

[image]

Is it not possible to use a Microsoft Access in Xamarin Android?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can convert the Access DB to SQLite

Comment: You need oleDB support on Android. You don't have that. And AFTER and if you could obtain oleDB support, you THEN also need a Android working copy of the JET (now ACE) database engine. That also does not exist for Android. So, you missing two significant and key technologies here.  As others suggested, sqlite is likly your best bet. Note that on the desktop, you can have Access link to a sqlite db, and all of the forms, reports in Access should work fine. In other words, build db in sqlite, and then have both desktop Access and Android use the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Oledb` is old and may not supported right now as the error message mentioned.

You can use `ADO.NET framework.` or `SQLite-NET 3rd party library` as list in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/#data-access-overview) to access the data in database.

There are detailed steps of how to using them in the document.

Here are some threads I searched about `Oledb`: [How can I access Database .mdb file in Xamarin forms?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/129789/how-can-i-access-database-mdb-file-in-xamarin-forms)  and [unable-to-import-oledbconnection-in-dotnet-core-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993919/unable-to-import-oledbconnection-in-dotnet-core-entity-framework)